# jquery autocomplete not working when source is remote

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I am trying to set up a remote autocomplete with VB.Net and everything is working fine but the results do not display when the source is remote.

I have tried this pieces of code:

```
 $('#Filtro_Clientes').autocomplete({
                    source: "../shared/peticionajax.ashx?idpeticion=autocompletar_cliente_sistema",
                    delay: 500,
                });
```

And:

```
$('#Filtro_Clientes').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.getJSON("../shared/peticionajax.ashx?idpeticion=autocompletar_cliente_sistema&term=" + request.term, function (data) {                            
                        response(data);
                    });
                },
                delay: 500,
            });
```

I have tried to use a local source with JSON data obtained through the browser network listener and it worked perfectly:

```
var pruebas = [{ label: 'ELSEVIER (España)', value: '5224' }, { label: 'ELSEVIER (Holanda)', value: '14996' }, { label: 'ELSEVIER PRENSA, S.A.', value: '10852' }, { label: 'REED ELSEVIER', value: '14540' }]

$('#Filtro_Clientes').autocomplete({
                    source: pruebas,                   
                    delay: 500,
                });
```

The content of the variable is a copy and paste of the data returned by the server when using the remote source.

I can't find what is wrong with the code i hope you guys can help me.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

I have another autocomplete working with a [label1, label2, label3, ...] JSON format. Here is the code:

```
$('#Filtro_Sistema').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("../shared/peticionajax.ashx?idpeticion=autocompletar_sistema_peticionexpress&term=" + request.term, function (data) {
            response(data);
        });
    },
    delay: 500,
});
```

Comment: can you by putting full url instead of `../`

Comment: @curiousguy the url is working fine because the json response is being received in the client and when debugging the server side everthing works fine. Also, i have a similar autocomplete with the same url format working fine but receiving a [ label1, label2, label3, ...] JSON format response.